# HTTP Verb (GET, POST, ...), include (->) or comment (#) expected

Tags: playframework

I was following the tutorial (little movie) from de playframework website (http://www.playframework.com/). When I tried to compile my code I get this error:

```
    HTTP Verb (GET, POST, ...), include (->) or comment (#) expected
```

This is my routes file:

```
    # Routes
    # This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
    # ~~~~

    # Home page
    GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

    POST    /ploegen                    controllers.Application.addPloeg()
    Get     /ploegen                    controllers.Application.getPloegen()

    # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
    GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

And this is the method from my application.java file:

```
    public static Result getPloegen() {
    List<Ploeg> ploegen = Model.Finder(String.class, Ploeg.class).all();
    return ok(toJson(ploegen));
    }
```

Now what do I have to do to solve this error, because I don't really know what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change line:

```
Get     /ploegen                    controllers.Application.getPloegen()
```

to:

```
GET     /ploegen                    controllers.Application.getPloegen()
```